# TypeError: Cannot convert 0.5625 to EagerTensor of dtype int64 on Google Colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iqhSkMJF0UcNBR3FRCM4nun-OW5kyJN8?usp=sharing

```
# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(
'/content/drive/MyDrive/train/train', 
target_size=(224, 224), 
color_mode='rgb', 
class_mode="categorical")
# load and iterate validation dataset
valid_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(
'/content/drive/MyDrive/valid', 
target_size=(224, 224), 
color_mode='rgb', 
class_mode="categorical")
```

output:

Found 152 images belonging to 6 classes.

Found 33 images belonging to 6 classes.

```
model.fit(
train_it,
validation_data=valid_it,
steps_per_epoch=train_it.samples/train_it.batch_size,
validation_steps=valid_it.samples/valid_it.batch_size,
epochs=10)
```

output:

Epoch 1/10
5/4 [===============================] - ETA: -4s - loss: 2.4248 - accuracy: 0.4276

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

in <module()

```
  4     steps_per_epoch=train_it.samples/train_it.batch_size,
  5     validation_steps=valid_it.samples/valid_it.batch_size,
  6     epochs=10)
```

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)

```
104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
107 
108
```

TypeError: Cannot convert 0.5625 to EagerTensor of dtype int64

I tried to change the value of validation steps but in vain : (

Please help Orz

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem, my solution, because it cant take 0.53 as step size `int(round(train_it.samples/train_it.batch_size))`, as step size to get int step size

Answer (score -1):

uhh i solved it

it's version pb

should change version to 2.2.0(colab is 2.6.0)

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow 
!pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

use this hah